# Commons-lang StringUtils isNotBlank method still raise NPE

Tags: java, sonarqube

Does Sonar support commons-lang StringUtils ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

Env:

```
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.19.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 amd64
```

Community EditionVersion 7.6 (build 21501)
code to reproduce this issue:

```
public class DetectorImport {
    public String check1(Nonentity nonentity) {
        String s;
        if(nonentity == null) {
            s = null;
        }else {
            s = nonentity.getName();
        }
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)) {
            s = s.replaceAll("（", "(");
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

From this sonar google groups, it is mentioned that the common.langs methods are supported by sonar.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/aluTP63hfyA

> Maybe another approach could be for you to use other utility classes, commonly used across Java projects. We currently support methods from commons-lang StringUtils (v2, and v3), guava preconditions, and java 8 methods from java.util.Objects (nonNull, isNull, requireNonNull). As we know how these methods behave, we are able to correctly handle such call and discard similar FPs. Of course, I don't want to force you using such libraries to make the analyzer happy. :)

changing above code to following one indeed solve this issue:

```
public class DetectorImport {

    public String check1(Nonentity nonentity) {
        String s;
        if(nonentity == null) {
            s = null;
        }else {
            s = nonentity.getName();
        }
        if(s !=null) {
            s = s.replaceAll("（", "(");
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

The above question is copied from

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/commons-lang-stringutils-isnotblank-method-still-raise-npe/21517

Am not the OP in Sonar, but I provided my solution there. I had the exact same question, so I am copying the solution over to others who end up here.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the SonarScanner and not the maven sonar plugin for our scans. And for us the issue was that the “sonar.java.libraries” variable was not properly set. I added the target “`dependency:copy-dependencies`” as part of the maven execution. This copied all the dependencies to the right location, then I set the property `“-Dsonar.java.libraries=target/dependency”` and everything started working as it's supposed to.